# Finding layer based on source name using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, layers, vb.net, loop

I am relatively new at creating tools with ArcObjects and I am having trouble finding a layer based on the layer's source name by looping through all layers.  I've seen [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Get_Path_for_a_Layer_Snippet/004900000092000000/) that it is possible, but I am unable to get it to work.  Am I missing something simple or is there another approach that I should be taking?  I see [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000005w000000) it is possible to enumerate layers and loop through them, but I am still left trying to determine the source name of a layer.  My example below is looking for a layer whose source is a feature class named buildings.  If it helps, the dataset variable has a value of "Nothing" when I use a MessageBox to print the value of dataset.Name at each iteration.

```
'--other code to get editor, set up other variables, and start edit operation

Dim findName As String = "buildings"
Dim isLayerFound As Boolean = False
Dim map as IMap = m_Editor.Map
Dim subfield as Integer = 'some subfield integer

'--Check For Point Layer In Editing
If Not map Is Nothing Then
'--Loop through all of the map layers to find the desired one
    For i = 0 To map.LayerCount - 1
        Dim currentLayer As ILayer = map.Layer(i)
        Dim dataset As IDataset = CType(currentLayer, IDataset) 
        If dataset.Name = findName Then
            isLayerFound = True
            '--Make sure layer is editable
            If m_editLayers.IsEditable(currentLayer) Then
                '--Set layer for editing
                m_editLayers.SetCurrentLayer(currentLayer, subfield)
                Exit For
            Else
                m_Editor.AbortOperation()
                MessageBox.Show("Layer " + findName + " is not editable. Operation aborted")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    If isLayerFound = False Then
        m_Editor.AbortOperation()
        MessageBox.Show("Layer " + findName + " could not be found. Operation aborted")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the name of the dataset as stored in the database use `IDataset.BrowseName`. `IDataset.Name` will give you the layer name as it is named in ArcMap.

You should also test that the layer can be cast to `IDataset`: `If TypeOf currentLayer Is IDataset Then`... Things like group layers don't implement `IDataset`, and will cause an error.

Comment: Great, this may be my problem.  My layers are all grouped. Will my loop look into grouped layers?

Comment: No, for that you should use IEnumLayer. Here's an example of that: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119610/how-to-query-all-layers-in-arcmap-and-get-access-to-them-by-name-or-index/119636#119636

Comment: That did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to post my final working code:

```
'--Check For Point Layer In Editing
If Not map Is Nothing Then
    '--Loop through all of the map layers to find the desired one
    Dim enumLayer As IEnumLayer = map.Layers(Nothing, True)
    enumLayer.Reset()
    Dim currentLayer As ILayer = enumLayer.Next()
    Do Until currentLayer Is Nothing
        If TypeOf currentLayer Is IDataset And Not TypeOf currentLayer Is IRasterLayer Then
            Dim dataset As IDataset = currentLayer
            If dataset.BrowseName = findName Then
                isLayerFound = True
                '--Make sure layer is editable
                If m_editLayers.IsEditable(currentLayer) Then
                    '--Set layer for editing
                    m_editLayers.SetCurrentLayer(currentLayer, subfield)
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    m_Editor.AbortOperation()
                    MessageBox.Show("Layer" + findName+ " is not editable. Operation aborted")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        End If
        currentLayer = enumLayer.Next()
    Loop
    If isLayerFound = False Then
        m_Editor.AbortOperation()
        MessageBox.Show("Layer " + findName + " could not be found. Operation aborted")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```